# Passing fields to Scala subclass constructors that have Java parents without similar constructors

Tags: scala, constructor

I have an abstract base class, written in Scala, that extends a 3rd party (open source) Java 7 class:

```
// The 3rd party Java 7 class
public class Fizz {
    private Foo foo;
    private Buzz buzz;

    public Fizz() {
        // ...
    }

    public Fizz(Buzz buzz) {
        // ...
    }

    // Getters and setters for foo + buzz down here
}

// My Scala classes
abstract class Bar(val foo : Foo) extends Fizz {
  // So I want my Bar API to accept a Foo, create an instance of Fizz via
  // its no-arg ctor, and then call setFoo(...) with the foo accepted here.
}

class SkyBar extends Bar {
  // ...
}

class SpaceBar extends Bar {
  // ...
}
```

So basically I want to be able to construct new `SkyBar` and `SpaceBar` instances and *force* them to accept a `Foo` argument in their constructors. Subsequently I want the `Bar` constructor to:

1. Call its `super()` (no-arg) parent constructor on `Fizz`; but then
2. Call its parent `setFoo(foo)` setter on the `Foo` instance passed in by its subclass constructors

I'm new to Scala and can't see the forest through the trees here. How do I make all this come together?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call `setFoo` in the body of `Bar`.

```
abstract class Bar(val foo: Foo) extends Fizz {
  setFoo(foo)
}
```

I don't think you want `foo` to be a public field though (which it is because of the `val` modifier):

```
abstract class Bar(foo: Foo) extends Fizz {
  setFoo(foo)
}
```

Otherwise you have an immutable field `foo` and a mutable (get/set)Foo property.

To elaborate on this point, if you make `foo` a `val` you would run into inconsistencies like this:

```
scala> class Bar(val foo: Foo) extends Fizz {
     |   setFoo(foo)
     | }
defined class Bar

scala> val bar = new Bar(Foo(1))
bar: Bar = Bar@3a384e3d

scala> bar.getFoo
res7: Foo = Foo(1)

scala> bar.foo
res8: Foo = Foo(1)

scala> bar.setFoo(Foo(2))

scala> bar.getFoo
res10: Foo = Foo(2)

scala> bar.foo
res11: Foo = Foo(1)  // still the old foo!!!
```

If you don't make it a public `val` there is no `bar.foo`.

Comment: Thanks @Jasper-M (+1) however I'm still not quite following 100%. I get what you're saing about `setFoo(foo)`, that makes total sense! But then you're losing me on the difference between fields vs. properties as well as their mutability. So if I use the first example (`val foo : Foo`), would `foo` be a "field" or a "property"? Would it be public or private? And would it be mutable or immutable? Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb `val foo` in the constructor means you have a publicly accessible `val` or immutable field/property/instance variable `foo`. Without `val` it's just a parameter that's local to the constructor. Unless you reference it from inside an instance method of your class; then it becomes a private instance variable of the class, but that's totally transparent to the programmer.

Comment: Terms such as field vs property are a bit confusing, I only used them to distinguish between Scala `val` and Java `getter+setter+private variable`.